# PHP: calling javascript function with parameters from php

Tags: php, javascript, function, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to call JavaScript function with parameter that are PHP variables.
I have tried 2 approaches.

1. calling JavaScript function in PHP with script tags in echo
   i.e

   ```
   <?php
   echo '<script>initialize('.$lat.','.$lang.','.$zom.');</script>';
   ?>
   ```
2. assigning PHP variables values to JavaScript variables

   ```
    <script>
    var lat="<?php echo $lat;?>";
    var lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>";
    var zoom="<?php echo $zoom; ?>";
    alert(lat+lang+zoom);
    initialize(lat,lang,zoom);
    </script>
   ```

In first case function is called as I cross-checked from page source but parameters passed are undefined.
And in 2nd case values are successfully saved in JavaScript variables, check it by alert(), but function is not called.

Here is the whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">

    </script>
<?php
     if(  isset($_POST['lat']) && isset($_POST['lang']) && isset($_POST['zoom']) && isset($_POST['city'])):

        $lat=$_POST['lat']; 

        $lang=$_POST['lang'];

        $zoom=$_POST['zoom'];

        $city=$_POST['city'];
        $zom=(int)$zoom;
              var_dump($lang);
        var_dump($lat);
        //var_dump($zoom);
              var_dump($zom);
          //echo '<script>initialize('.$lat.','.$lang.','.$zom.');</script>';

    endif;

?>          


<script>
var lat="<?php echo $lat; ?>";
var lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>";
var zoom="<?php echo $zoom; ?>";
alert(lat+lang+zoom);
initialize(lat,lang,zoom);
</script>

    <script>


function initialize(a,b,zom){        

    if (!a || !b ||!zom){ 
    alert('came on not' +a+b +zom);

    //      var centerLoc=new google.maps.LatLng( 33.61701054652337,73.37824736488983);

          zoom=16;

    }

    else

    {
        alert('came');

        var zoom =parseInt(zom);

        var centerLoc=new google.maps.LatLng(a,b);

    }

       var mapProp = {

            center:centerLoc,

            zoom:zoom,

            //mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE

       };  

       var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap") ,mapProp);

            marker=new google.maps.Marker({

                  position:centerLoc,

                  title:'Click to zoom'

             });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {

                map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1);

                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

       });

            marker.setMap(map);

}

       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>

</head>

<body style= "background-color:gainsboro;">

    <form method="POST"  action="myPage.php" >

        Enter latitude:     <input type ="text" name="lat" id="lat" / ><br/>

        Enter longitude:    <input type ="text" name="lang"  id="lang"/ ><br/>

        Enter City Name:    <input type="text" name="city" id="city"/><br/>

        Enter Zoom level:   <input type ="text" name="zoom"  id="zoom"/ ><br/>

                        <input type="button" value ="Perview" onclick=" initialize(

                     document.getElementById('lat').value,

                     document.getElementById('lang').value,

                     document.getElementById('zoom').value)"/>

                        <input type="Submit"  value="Save" />

    </form>

                        <center><div id="googleMap"  style="width:1000px;height:500px;"></div></center>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Check the JavaScript console for errors.

Comment: When you execute `echo '<script>initialize('.$lat.','.$lang.','.$zom.');</script>';`, what do you get in the source code of the generated page?

Comment: Try to debug your js - for example, using Chrome's console

Comment: Do you call this function, or it just "exists"? You would perhaps need to call it in `body onload`, `something onclick` etc.

Comment: `var lang="="<?php echo $lang; ?>";` seems a little weird. What does it look like after PHP processed it?

Comment: this is the error in firebug.but i dont know what it is. The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. @ http://localhost/microdata/microdata/myPage.php

Comment: @ Mathieu Imbert sory it is just a typo.var lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>";

Comment: @Rabeel this is not the error that causes malfunction

Comment: @Rabeel, what do the values contain? Can you `var_dump()` them right before composing the script tag? Also, if this is about latitude and longitude, you might have misspelled `$lang` (short for longitude is `$long`, not `$lang`)

Comment: $lang is just a variable ,its name will not create any problem. and $lang $lat are string values but $zoom is integer

Comment: @Rabeel, what exactly do they contain? Can you post the output of `var_dump()` for all 3 variables?

Comment: @Rid, here it is:string '70' (length=2)

string '30' (length=2)

int 5

Comment: @Rabeel, I'm noticing another typo: in the first example, you're using a variable named `$zom`, but in the second example you're using `$zoom`.

Comment: @Rid, no it is not.$zom is variable that has been converted from string to integer. and $zoom is in string

Comment: @Rabeel, and what is the string generated by the first example?

Comment: @Rid, it is: initialize(30,70,5);

Comment: @Rabeel, that is valid JavaScript, therefore your problem is elsewhere. Can you post the `initialize()` function?

Comment: @Rid Question updated with initialize function.

Comment: you are going abou this entirely wrong, why not just have an api endpoint in php that returns you lat/long? Then make an AJAX call to it, get the lat/long and finally run your initialize? Injecting php into script is not a good idea and vice versa...

Answer (score 6):

Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).  If you don't there will always be the possibility you escaped your data incorrectly as it passes from the PHP to the HTML/JS layer.

```
$vars = array($lat, $lang, $zoom);
// JSON_HEX_TAG and JSON_HEX_AMP are to remove all possible surprises that could be
// caused by vars that contain '</script>' or '&' in them. The rules for 
// escaping/encoding inside script elements are complex and vary depending 
// on how the document is parsed.
$jsvars = json_encode($vars, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP);

echo "<script>initialize.apply(null, $jsvars)</script>";
```

In general, for your sanity, all data that is in PHP that you need to make available to js running on the current page should be collected into a single PHP array and then placed into a single js object.  For example:

```
<?php
$jsdata = array(
   'formvars' => array(
                      'lat' => $lat,
                      'lang' => $lang,
                      'zoom' => $zoom
    ),
   'username' => $username,
   'some_other_data' => $more stuff
);
?>
<script>
  var JSDATA = <?=json_encode($jsdata, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP )?>;
  initialize(JSDATA.formvars.lat, JSDATA.formvars.lang, JSDATA.formvars.zoom);
</script>
```

Now there is only a single point of contact between the JS and PHP/HTML layers so you can easily keep track of what you are putting into the JS namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Call the function when the browser finished loading the javascript.

```
<script>
     window.onload = function() {
         var lat="<?php echo $lat; ?>";
         var lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>";
         var zoom="<?php echo $zoom; ?>";
         alert(lat+lang+zoom);
         initialize(lat,lang,zoom);
     };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I dont need it to be called on window load

Answer (score 1):

I found some really good examples on [Calling a javascript function from php](http://www.hoverdroids.com/tutorials/php/calling-a-javascript-function-from-php/) and it appears you can also run the code online at [PhpFiddle.org](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9254ef97cf085e276f46)

Just in case the links break, here are the examples:

Example 1: Calling without parameters

```
<?php
echo "<a href='http://www.hoverdroids.com/2015/06/10/calling-a-javascript-function-from-php/'>Full example at: http://www.hoverdroids.com/2015/06/10/calling-a-javascript-function-from-php/</a>";
echo "<p>Add whatever PHP you want here...</p>";
?>
<!--This JS function can be defined here or a separate file since so long as it gets created in JS space'-->
<script>
    function callAlert(){
        alert('A alert without a parameter');
    }
</script>
<script>
    callAlert();
</script>
<?php
?>
```

Example 2: Calling with a single parameter

```
<?php
echo "<a href='http://www.hoverdroids.com/2015/06/10/calling-a-javascript-function-from-php/'>Full example at: http://www.hoverdroids.com/2015/06/10/calling-a-javascript-function-from-php/</a>";
echo "<p>Add whatever PHP you want here...</p>";

//Data that is going to be passed into the JavaScript function. Try to keep all vars together so
//that it's easier to track down the php/javascript interaction
$jsdata = 'MyName';
?>
<!--This JS can be here or a separate file since all it's doing is defining a function in the JS space'-->
<script>
    function callAlert(text){
        alert(text);
    }
</script>
<!--This JS must be defined with the php since it's using previously defined php variables -->
<script>
    var JSDATA = <?=json_encode($jsdata, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP )?>;

    //Prompt using a single var
    callAlert(JSDATA);
</script>
<?php
?>
```

Example 3: Calling using an array of parameters

```
<?php
echo "<a href='http://www.hoverdroids.com/2015/06/10/calling-a-javascript-function-from-php/'>Full example at: http://www.hoverdroids.com/2015/06/10/calling-a-javascript-function-from-php/</a>";
echo "<p>Add whatever PHP you want here...</p>";

$myname = 'MyName';
$yourname = 'YourName';

//Data that is going to be passed into the JavaScript function. Try to keep all vars together so
//that it's easier to track down the php/javascript interaction
$jsdata = array(
                'input' => $myname,
                'array_input' => array(
                                        'name' => $yourname
                ),
);
?>
<!--This JS can be here or a separate file since all it's doing is defining a function in the JS space'-->
<script>
    function callAlert(text){
        alert(text);
    }
</script>
<!--This JS must be defined with the php since it's using previously defined php variables -->
<script>
    var JSDATA = <?=json_encode($jsdata, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP )?>;

    //Prompt using a single var in the array
    callAlert(JSDATA.input);


    //Prompt using a var from a nested array    
    callAlert(JSDATA.array_input.name);
</script>
<?php
?>
```

Comment: Who would possibly downvote this answer? I provided three examples that answered the question with incrementally increasingly complexity along with videos that explain the point for users who prefer audio/video solutions. So, to the downvoter, please explain instead of doing a hit-and-run!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just call on the predefined java script code like  jsFunction() ;  in your php code